# .htaccess 301 redirect to the same page with no query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to create a condition that if page has parameter in URL like ?print=1 - redirect this page to itself without any querystring.

Example:

I want this page:

```
http://sos-med.com/en/specific_page.html?print=1&ok=1
```

tp redirect (301) to the same URL with no Query string:

```
http://sos-med.com/en/specific_page.html
```

---

My code is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^*print=*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}?
```

I have no test server, so can you tell me if my code is ok?

The code above is for every page on website. And before implementing that rule I would like to try the redirect for one specific page (see my example).
How to modify the code to work with "specific_page.html" only?

I want only .htaccess solution, not PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, your `%{QUERY_STRING}` regex isn't right, and you're missing the 301 redirect flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^print=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Try that.

---

> Thanks, and If I want to redirect single specific page: sos-med.com/en/aaa.html?print=1&ok=1 to sos-med.com/en/aaa.html ? –

Then you'd change what the rule matches against:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^print=.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en/aaa.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, and If I want to redirect single specific page: 
http://sos-med.com/en/aaa.html?print=1&ok=1 to http://sos-med.com/en/aaa.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?print= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```