# .htaccess redirect without query string

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect (note without query strings):

```
http://www.reviews.com/review/review_review.cfm?review_id=135223
```

to

```
http://www.reviews.com/
```

The current rule:

```
Redirect 301 /review/review_review.cfm http://www.reviews.com/
```

Causes the original URL to redirect to `http://www.reviews.com/?review_id=135223`

Based on a few stack questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956475/remove-query-string-from-redirected-url-with-htaccess) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978066/htaccess-301-redirect-to-the-same-page-with-no-query-string), I should be able to add a `?` to the Redirect rule as below:

```
Redirect 301 /review/review_review.cfm http://www.reviews.com/?
```

but this redirects to `http://www.reviews.com/?`. The trailing ? remains. How do I get rid of this it's killing me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't get rid of the extraneous `?` using mod_alias. The `?` will prevent a query string from getting appended but with mod_alias, it unfortunately includes a `?` as part of the redirect. However, mod_rewrite won't, because adding the `?` to the end, which tells it to not include any existing query string, works the same way as mod_alias, but after that it gets processed again by mod_alias, minus the trailing `?`, so the end result is no trailing `?` at the end of the URL. So something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?review/review_review.cfm$ http://www.reviews.com/? [L,R=301]
```

And this would replace the `Redirect` statement.

Comment: For a R=301 type redirect, you can also omit the URL in the redirect, like "/? [L,R=301]"

Comment: @NickPyett You can remove the `http://www.reviews.com` part whether it's a 301 redirect or not. The only reason you need it there is if the hostname you are redirecting **to** is different than the hostname that the request is made for. In the case of this particular question, you don't really need the `http://www.reviews.com` part and the target can simply be: `/?`.